# Lex program to check the structure(struct)

Tags: c, lex

I'm trying to create program to check if the input such as `struct st{ int j; real i; }` it should print correct otherwise not correct.

but I have this error

```
    prog.l: In function 'yylex':
gyg.l:10:5: error: expected expression before '{' token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unquoted/unescaped space inside your pattern. Lex uses spaces to separate the pattern from the action, so it thinks `("struct")" "({iden})+` is your pattern and your C code is:

```
"{"({defs}|({defs})*)"}"";"    {printf(" correct ");}`
```

Clearly the first part of that is not valid C code and that's why you get a compilation error. To fix this problem, remove the space, put it in quotes or escape it with a backslash.

Comment: did you mean the space in ("struct")" "({iden})+  
can you explain please?

Comment: @lena No, that one's in quotes. I mean the space between the `+` and the `"{"`, which is why the `+` is the last character that's seen as part of the pattern and everything afterwards is seen as part of the C code.

Comment: No no there is no space between them ("struct")" "({iden})+"{"({defs}|({defs})*)"}"";"    {printf(" correct ");}

Comment: @lena In the code that you posted in your question, there absolutely is a space after the `+` and if I remove that space, the code compiles fine.

Comment: Yes I forgot to update the program, but after the change I see the error shown in the question

Comment: @lena I don't. Your edited code compiles without error for me.

Comment: Now every think is ok thanks for your helping !

Answer (score 0):

LEX is used to create a lexical analyzer which takes a sequence of characters as input and produces a sequence of symbols as output. In your example those symbols would be something like

```
STRUCT IDENT { IDENT IDENT ; IDENT IDENT ; }
```

To analyze the syntax you need a different program called YACC which is a parser generator. Here is a tutorial on LEX and YACC:

https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/systems/tutorials/au-lexyacc/